# Cone of feasible directions and radial cone

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, convex-cone

I am trying to prove

if $A$ is convex and $x^*\in A$, then $D(A,x^*)=cone(A-x^*)$, where $D(A,x^*)=\{ d\in \mathbb{R^n}| \exists \delta >0$ such that $x^* +td \in A, \forall t \in (0,\delta) \}$ and $A-x^*=\{ a-x^*|a\in A\}$.

Definition of cone: $Cone(A) = \{ \lambda a\ | a\in A , \lambda \geq 0\}$

What I have tried so far:

I believe $cone(A-x^*)=\{ \lambda (a-x^*)|  a\in A , \lambda \geq 0\}$

Since $A$ is convex, $A-x^*$ is also convex. 
 Since $A-X^*$ is convex, $cone(A-x^*)$ is convex cone.
So, $cone(A-x^*)=\{ \sum ^k _{i=1} \lambda_i x^{(i)}| k\in \mathbb{N}, \lambda_i \geq0, x^{(i)}\in A-x^*\}$

I am trying somehow to find a way to connect $\{ \sum ^k _{i=1} \lambda_i x^{(i)}| k\in \mathbb{N}, \lambda_i \geq0, x^{(i)}\in A-x^*\}$
 and $D(A,x^*)$, but I am not sure....

Please help me.

Comment: What is your definition for $\text{cone}(A - x^*)$? Also, by $A - x^*$ do you mean $\{a - x^*\mid a \in A\}$ or $\{a \mid a \in A, a \ne x\}$?

Comment: Thank you for asking, I edited. It means $\{a-x^*|a \in A \}$

Comment: Prove that $D(A, x^*) = D(A - x^*, 0)$. Then prove your result in the special case where $x^* = 0$ I.e., if $0 \in A$, then $D(A, 0) = \text{Cone}(A)$. The definitions of $D$ and $\text{Cone}$ are similar in this case (though this does require that $A$ is convex). Finally, using the first result, show the complete theorem.

Answer (score 1):

To help you with the outline I've provided in my last comment, to prove $D(A,0) = \text{Cone}(A)$ when $A$ is convex and $0 \in A$, you need to prove two things:

- $\text{Cone}(A)\subseteq D(A,0)$
- $D(A,0) \subseteq \text{Cone}(A)$

The first is the harder the prove, and requires both that $A$ is convex and $0 \in A$. The second holds for any $A$.

To prove $\text{Cone}(A)\subseteq D(A,0)$, let $d \in \text{Cone}(A)$. Then there exist $\lambda > 0, a \in A$ with $d = \lambda a$. Let $\delta = \frac 1\lambda$. If $t \in (0,\delta)$, let $q = \frac t\delta = t\lambda$, so $q \in (0,1)$, and $td = \left(\frac q\lambda\right)\left(\lambda a\right) = qa$. But since $0, a \in A$, so is every point on the line segment connecting them. I.e., $td = qa \in A$. Therefore $d \in D(A, 0)$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now, everything makes sense.

Comment: Would you please double check $td=(\frac{q}{\lambda})(\lambda a)=qa$? I don't think $td=(\frac{q}{\lambda})(\lambda a)$ is right.

Comment: @measurehell - you are right, I'd turned it around. It was an easy fix, though: just set $\delta = \frac 1\lambda$ instead.